# Public key won't import in GPG, "no valid user ID", "unknown algorithm 100"

Tags: gnupg

I received a public key, starting in

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGP Desktop 10.2.1 (Build 5033)
```

When I `--import` it, I get (some fields substituted with `x`)

```
gpg: key CC49xxxxxxxxxxxx: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key CC49xxxxxxxxxxxx: no valid user IDs
gpg: this may be caused by a missing self-signature
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
```

When I `--list-packets` it, I get

```
# off=0 ctb=99 tag=6 hlen=3 plen=269
:public key packet:
        version 4, algo 1, created 1570xxxxxx, expires 0
        pkey[0]: [2048 bits]
        pkey[1]: [17 bits]
        keyid: CC49xxxxxxxxxxxx
# off=272 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=47
:user ID packet: "xxxxxx xxxxxxx<xxxxxxx.xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.com>"
# off=321 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=1705
:signature packet: algo 100, keyid 0000000000000000
        version 4, created 1570xxxxxx, md5len 0, sigclass 0x10
        digest algo 8, begin of digest 00 00
        hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2019-xx-xx)
        hashed subpkt 3 len 4 (sig expires after 3y0d0h0m)
        hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 0C)
        hashed subpkt 100 len 1674 (experimental / private subpacket)
        unknown algorithm 100
```

I'm running GnuPG 2.2.27 with libgcrypt 1.8.7.

I get that `algo 100` is some proprietary extension, perhaps sneaking an X.509 certificate.

Is there a way to normalize that public key so that I can import it, without bothering my correspondent (like, supplying a signature made with my private key to certify the user ID)? Would it then work to encipher? To check a signature?